# How to check variable is either 0 or 1 in express-validator

Tags: express

I need to check req.body.isIssueFixed is 0 or 1 , I am trying in epress-validator

```
req.checkBody(isIssueFixed , 'isIssueFixed  is not a boolean value ').isBoolean();
```

but isBoolean is not an method . How to fix this and where i can chck all the available methods of express-validator ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Express-validator uses node-validator, a list of built in validators are available here: https://github.com/chriso/validator.js#validators. Alternatively you can add your own custom validators: https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#customvalidators

isBoolean() is a built in validator so your issue must lie elsewhere. In your code is the variable `isIssueFixed` properly defined as the key of the parameter that you are validating? Is the express middleware configured correctly? Can you post what error you are getting?

Comment: I have fixed that issue , my express-validator version was 2.x.x updated it on 3.2.1 now it is working fine